# What is the difference between "tall and high?"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, word-order

When can we use them? Are they the same or different?

"How tall is that building?" Can I use "high" in that sentence or not?

"This is the tallest mountain in Japan." Can I use "highest" in that sentence instead of "tallest"?

Answer (score 0):

I think "tall" would be used when you can visualize both the bottom or top of something, or when the size is greater than the average one.

> How **tall** are you?
>   That building is **tall**.

Check the definition [tall](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/tall) sense 1, 2 or 4.

"high" is almost always used for elevation, so I would use:

> This is the **highest** mountain in Japan.
>   How **high** is the plane flying?

Check the definition of [high](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/high) sense 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Tall** is an adjective describing a *characteristic* of an object:

*The man is tall.*

*The building is tall.*

*The ant is not tall.*

**High** describes *where* the object is:

*How high is that cloud?*

**Height** describes a *characteristic* of an object:

*Please record your height and weight.*

---