# Is it possible to say "That building is getting more and more higher."?

Tags: word-usage, comparative-constructions

I'm not sure if it's correct to say "more and more higher" because "more and more expensive" is possible. But as you can see, in the second example the comparative form of the adjective expensive is "more expensive", so this expression indicates that something is more expensive each time. Can I use "more and more" with the same usage with short adjectives such as "high"?

Answer (score 5):

Where the adjective is short enough to take the comparative in *-er,* as with *high,* the usual form of the expression is “higher and higher.”

Comment: And for a [building it is preferable](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/152376/51214) to say *taller and taller* (IMHO).

Comment: Um. I would use _higher_ rather than _taller_ for a building 90% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> That building is getting **higher and higher**.

I think *higher* is better, because the building elevation (as in skyscrapers) is probably in such a context. But in the end it is context dependent.

Having said that, the distinction between *high* and *tall* is better discussed in other ELL posts, such as *[What is the difference between “tall and high?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29569/what-is-the-difference-between-tall-and-high)* and *[“high” vs. “tall”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/high-vs-tall)*.

In the context of the question as I understand it, I would rather say:

> That building **keeps** getting higher. (or *taller* if you prefer)

Comment: I agree with _higher_ rather than _taller_ for a buidling. _Taller_ seems to me to apply to people. I don't recall saying that building is really really tall.